# How is the traffic in York opinion based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I got [my question on traffic in York](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25817/1264) closed because it's apparently "primarily opinion-based", but didn't get any suggestions on how exactly that was the case.  I would have thought a question about the state of traffic in a particular location would be simple to answer without an opinion.  Can someone please let me know how I can improve this question?

Comment: Looks like people started voting to close when it asked if traffic was "better" then others sadly piled on even after you changed it to be a simple factual comparison

Comment: The new wording it is objectively measurable and therefore, I reopened it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, when it was 'better' it was simply a matter of clarifying what you meant by that. 'Better' has been historically a dirty word on here, when people ask 'what's the best route to take' or 'the best lake to visit' etc.

I don't believe I voted to close though, despite being the one asking for clarification there - I was pretty sure what you meant, but wanted to clarify.

Anyway, it's back open again :)

Comment: Thanks - I'll note to avoid "better"/"best" even if it should be fairly obvious what it means.

Comment: @Mark Just curious, what other possible answers to what "better traffic" means are there? "By 'better traffic', I mean *more* traffic and congestion, because I'm a carspotter"? "By 'better traffic', I mean a higher percentage of yellow cars and cars with WWJD stickers?"

Comment: @user568458 like I said, I wasn't the one to close it, I just knew it was a 'dirty' word on here. You'd have to ask the others.
Looking at it he asked originally if better to drive on a weekday or weekend, so it was quite a different question than it is now.